# Time Difference in DATEDIFF in column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with Terminal connection logs. From this table there are columns 'EventTime', 'TerminalID' and 'Detail'.

My current query looks like this:

```
select 
   C_EventTime, L_TID,
   CASE L_Detail
      when '11' then 'Terminal Disconnected'
      when '12' then 'Terminal Connected'
   END as 'Detail'
from 
   dbo.tTerminalStateLog
where 
   L_Detail in (11,12) and C_EventTime >= '20140310000000'
order by 
   L_TID, C_EventTime
```

The output looks like this:

```
C_EventTime     L_TID  Detail
----------------------------------------------
20140310110637  5000     Terminal Connected
20140312142909  5000     Terminal Disconnected 
20140313173850  5000     Terminal Connected
20140313233512  5000     Terminal Disconnected 
20140313233610  5000     Terminal Connected
20140310013506  5001     Terminal Disconnected
20140310013517  5001     Terminal Connected
20140310222519  5001     Terminal Disconnected 
20140310222532  5001     Terminal Connected
20140312165526  5001     Terminal Disconnected 
20140312165536  5001     Terminal Connected
20140310121415  12300    Terminal Connected
20140310122031  12300    Terminal Disconnected 
20140311083532  12300    Terminal Connected
20140311084218  12300    Terminal Disconnected 
20140311085141  12300    Terminal Connected
20140311085212  12300    Terminal Disconnected 
20140322115023  13100    Terminal Disconnected 
20140322115543  13100    Terminal Connected
20140322142655  13100    Terminal Disconnected 
20140322144834  13100    Terminal Connected
20140327192448  13100    Terminal Disconnected
```

I would like to count the duration between each Disconnected and Connected terminal state, count each offline connection duration on each L_TID and give an output of Rows = TerminalID and Columns 24hrs, 168hrs(week) and 720hrs(month).

Should i break the varchar up into a more readable format first by:

```
    DECLARE @x VARCHAR(14)
    SET @x = '20040102102425'
    SELECT  @x,
    STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@x, 9, 0, ' '), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':'),
    CAST(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@x, 9, 0, ' '), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':') AS DATETIME)
```

for output:

```
    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
    20040102102425      20040102 10:24:25   2004-01-02 10:24:25.000
```

and then count the datetime connection_states for a total time value after I run:

```
    select datediff(ss, '2010-01-22 15:29:55' , '2010-01-22 15:30:09')
```

How can this be run to see the total disconnected state for each Terminal ID?

Example of what I have in mind:

```
    L_TID       24 hrs        1 Week        30 days
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    5000       00:42:24     04:21:07       16:49:46      
    5001       00:09:38     01:38:01       05:32:19
    123000     01:05:59     09:29:15       11:58:19
```

Hope someone can give advise.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using - SQL Server?

Comment: I am using SQl server 2008. sorry for not stating this.

Answer (score 0):

If its Oracle, then you can try something like

```
SELECT l_tid, 
       c_eventtime - Lag(c_eventtime, 2, Trunc(c_eventtime)) 
                       over ( 
                         ORDER BY c_eventtime) AS PriorRowEventTime, 
       details 
FROM   (SELECT l_tid, 
               To_date(c_eventtime, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') c_eventtime, 
               details 
        FROM   table1);
```

Comment: HI realspirituals. I am not using Oracle.

Comment: SQL server is not having lead or lag analytical functions, and you can try using joins